# Why does Ohm's law not work in a simple lightbulb circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

I was studying the module "Physical foundations of Computer Science" and was asked to construct a circuit with 3 lightbulbs which operate at $110V$ and can develop powers of $55W$, $55W$ and $110W$ respectively. Later, I was asked to construct a circuit which had a source of power of $220V$ (In this case, we needed resistors). Nevertheless, what surprised me was that whilst trying to calculate the resistance the 3 lightbulbs needed for the $220V$ circuit, I wasn't able to use Ohm's Law but I rather had to use the Joule effect formula. The circuit I propose would look like so:

[image: Circuit diagram]

I had to calculate resistance like so: $P=\frac{V^2}{R}$ instead of $V=IR$, why might this be? Also, why do we not take into account the intensity that the cables might carry?

Comment: Calculating the resistance needed for what? What are you trying to do?

Comment: It is just an exercise to understand solid state physics and ideal conditions. No tungsten filaments are taken into account in such exercise. It is a "virtual" construction rather.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate it for a specific wattage?

Comment: I was simply trying to understand why Ohm's law wasn't applicable in the 220V case. Also, if we needed to use the Joule effect formula, we are not taking into account (at least in the formula) the intensity that the cables carry, which sparked my curiosity.

Comment: I am going to correct myself: it was not about solid state physics, it is about the concept of electric current.

Comment: Your comments to mmesser314 describe things not in your post. This leaves me wondering just what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @BobD I had an exercise where we were given specific wattages for 3 lightbulbs and that the voltage at which they work at is $110V$. Later, we were asked to build a circuit with the same components but with a $220V$ battery, although in this case we needed resistors. I hadn't talked about wattages in the exercise I proposed but they were given. The part I was trying to focus about was why we couldn't use Ohm's law for the $220V$ scenario. All these scenarios are built virtually and/or on paper.

Comment: Look, half the people here are really trying to tell you that without even a circuit diagram, we cannot even know what it is you are complaining about, and nobody can meaningfully help you.

Answer (score 3):

Mmesser's short answer shows how Ohm's law still applies in this case. But once you move on to the next step of the analysis, materials science tries to trick you into disbelieving Ohm's law again, even though it still holds- as follows.

However, first let's take a general look into Ohm's law. It is a statement about linear system response that ties together effort, flow, and resistance terms and as such is fundamental enough to be applicable not just to electrical systems but *any* linear system with constant coefficients. If there's one thing it *isn't*, it's tautological.

Imagine now you measure the filament resistance of one of your bulbs with an ohmmeter. Now you know the resistance and the rated voltage of the bulb and to your dismay you can't get the right answer for the wattage of the bulb, as printed on the bulb by its manufacturer. The measured resistance is too low to yield the nameplate wattage!

This is because the tungsten filament, like most metals, exhibits a significant temperature coefficient of resistance: the hotter it gets, the higher its resistance becomes. (This is usually explained as being because its atoms are jiggling around more vigorously when hot which increases their ability to scatter electrons flowing by.)

So if we're going to write down the constituitive relation for effort, flow, and resistance (i.e., Ohm's law) in this case, we simply account for the fact that R is not a constant in that equation but instead a *variable*, and as the filament heats up we substitute a new value for R based on the instantaneous value of the filament temperature. Ohm's law still holds at every individual step in the process. (Thanks to my old engineering professor Donald L. Margolis for teaching me this important point in 1974.)

So... the wattage output of the bulb is established by its resistance *when hot* and not when cold. Note here that the ohmmeter does not force enough current through the filament to get it hot, and so it measures the *cold resistance* of the filament.  Ohm's law is right again.

Comment: Of course, this bumps up into the issue of what we mean by Ohm's law. The *definition* of (static) resistance is $R:= V/I$, and so if we take Ohm's law to mean $V=IR$ then it is a tautology (almost) completely empty of physical content. Alternatively, some would call Ohm's law the statement that $R$ is constant, so $V\propto I$, and this scenario would be an example of the *breakdown* of this assumption due to the heating of the material. From a certain standpoint its a matter of definition, I suppose, but I tend towards the latter.

Comment: I'm going to edit. -NN

Answer (score 1):

You know P and V, so you can calculate I and R.

If you knew I and V, you could calculate P and R.

Comment: But if I previously calculate $I$ with $P=IV$, then I also know $I$, or am I wrong? I think I was able to calculate the intensity because I was given the initial power the lightbulbs had and was later asked to use these same lightbulbs in a circuit with $220 V$ where you needed to use resistances.

Comment: You are right. In that case you could then use R = V/I.

Comment: In which case? In normal conditions (I was given the voltage to be $110V$) or in the $220V$ circuit?